# How to remove index.php from url in magento?

Tags: url

I would like to remove index.php from url ( includes home, product, category, admin pages).

1. Is it possible to remove index.php from my site?
2. Having index.php url as well as non index.php url count for duplicate url, i.e will it affect SEO?

I tried many procedures nothing worked out.
Contacted my hosting provider, they tried editing .htacces but they all so failed and said please ask some magento expert.

Some links what I tried:

http://www.indianwebportal.com/remove-index-php-url-magento

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474740/how-to-remove-index-php-from-urls

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16938860/how-do-i-remove-index-php-from-the-url-in-magento

Any help would be great.
Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I tried all those, but when we enter in url manually index.php works.

Comment: So? What's the problem? If there are no links anywhere pointing to your website with `index.php` in them....

Comment: I doubt having two url different url to same page will be duplicate issue, so it may affect SEO. Am I right? If not pointing the truth is we are having two url.

Comment: did you re-index after changing configuration ?

Comment: Yes I re-indexed, changed SEO settings in Config, Flushed Cache,..

Comment: _Yeah, I tried all those, but when we enter in url manually index.php works_ Yep, it is going to work manually, that's the way the Magento routing works. SEO friendly URLs should have been enabled from the beginning. Just enable your canonicals and let Google sort the issues out over time. Otherwise, you're just overthinking it.

Comment: @ Fiasco Labs,so index.php is not a problem, am I right?

Comment: If you got the SEO friendly URLs set up properly and all the links you hover over are showing the URL without index.php, then you've done your job. Now enable canonicals so Google knows what is authoritatively the correct page and let them reindex. Just because you can manually stick index.php in the URL and have Magento serve out a page just means Magento serves out a page. Hover the links on that page and you should see links without index.php.

Comment: @ Fiasco Labs. what you are saying is good and logical, but having url without index.php will be the best.